# google map api create a path with set of lattitude and longitude

Tags: android, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I am building a android/ web application. In with user can save a set of gps data ( latitude and longitude ) in our DB for eg my db looks like

```
Id     |    UserId     |   time                |    latitude     |      longitude
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      |    12         |  2012-05-05 11:11:01  | 12.21547        |      22.1245789
1      |    12         |  2012-05-05 12:13:01  | 12.21547        |      22.1245779
1      |    12         |  2012-05-05 13:11:01  | 12.27547        |      22.1745789
1      |    12         |  2012-05-05 14:11:01  | 12.30547        |      22.3045789
1      |    12         |  2012-05-05 14:22:01  | 12.36547        |      22.3555789
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My question is can I create a path Google Map using the above data. 
Straightly .... I want to draw the user traveled path in Google map with the above data

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not, use a polyline, V2: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference?hl=en#GPolyline or V3: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#Polyline

Comment: Are you really using the Google Maps API v2? If not, you should change the tag, if you are using v2, I hope you realize it is deprecated and not recommended for new applications.

Comment: hi geocodezip... thanks for your comment ... really I just started the project ... is it possible if my db length is more than 100 rows ?